# How to separate the query result to corespond with other query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to display the name of picture uploader on hover over picture they uploaded but I get displayed all the names from query over each picture or just the first name from query result over each picture. I tried to do it with foreach, while, for(setting $rowz[$i] and incrementing the $i variable) and i even tryed to create function that would display name but i always end up with error or wrong output. Keep in mind im super new to php and sql.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM picture WHERE status=1";
$rs=doQuery($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
    echo"<img class='picture__img' src='{$row['url']}' >";
    $sql="SELECT name FROM user u, picture p WHERE p.status=1 AND p.user_id=u.user_id";
    $rz=doQuery($db,$sql);
    $rowz=mysqli_fetch_array($rz);
    foreach ($rowz as $k){
            echo"<div class='picture__name'>{$rowz[$k]}</div>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the output you receive vs expected?

Comment: Why are you using `foreach` and `$rowz[$k]` instead of skipping the foreach and just do: `$rowz['name']`?

Comment: _"display the name of picture uploader on hover over picture"_ - How are the names and the images connected? You seem to output all names after each other without any identifiers that tells you what images the names belongs to?

Comment: You will also LOOSE the first result of your first query as you do a `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs);` BEFORE you start the while looping

Comment: You also fetch all names for all images on every iteration in your loop. You should look into using JOIN in your first query and get both the image and the name directly instead of making queries inside the while-loop.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Last thing i tried was foreach with [$k]. Before that i tried with echo"<div class='picture__name'>{$rowz['name']}</div>"; in while loop but would end up with every name i pulled with query being displayed on every picture.
Pictures are connected with users (names) with user_id. There is table Users with user_id as primary key and there's also user_id in table Pictures that is foreign key that references to table Users. Doesnt that servers as indentifier to tell what image belongs to each user? Ok ill check how to use JOIN in my querys. Tnx

Comment: @GytisTG Ok 1st picture is output i get when i use 'while' loop: [link](https://ibb.co/dJ6vsnx)
2nd picture is the output i get when i use 'foreach' : [link](https://ibb.co/Sxrk9HT)
On 2nd picture i hoverd over the last picture and im trying to get "Quentin" over it.
Note that first six pictures are from Pero than four for Vladimir.

Comment: It serves as an identifier in your database, but not in your HTML, which is what I'm talking about. Where's the reference in HTML that shows which div with the name should be shown when hovering an image? The code you've posted will fetch all names but will only output the first in the list (which should be the same name) for each image. If you removed the foreach and just did `$rowz['name']` instead, it should give you an identical result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem i had. Thanks to Magnus I realised problem occured when i used more than one SQL query in loop. I created a single query using INNER JOIN to pull all the data i need and just printed the needed column.

```
$sql="SELECT picture.user_id, user.name, picture.url FROM picture INNER JOIN user ON picture.user_id=user.user_id WHERE picture.status=1";
$rs=doQuery($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
    echo"<img class='picture__img' src='{$row['url']}' >";
    echo"<div class='picture__name'>{$row['name']}</div>";
    }
```